# laravel relationship / cannot fetch child table data via parent table

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship

Bit confused on relationships, just don't know which one to be used. Attached picture for you to understand the structure.

Please help me with some basic structure, which relationship should I go with? How will be the model structure, migrations field..[here is the basic structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEPR1.jpg)

Comment: do not think category, country and range are common for 3 table. Work like they are seperated columns. If you didn't made it this way. And use just  belongsTo. Hope i understand correctly.

Comment: In general you will get a much better response putting the schema in the post as text rather than as an image.